# What was the first ever televised lottery?

Tags: game, television

The UK's National Lottery has been on TV since 1994. A similar state-owned lottery in Poland has been on air for much longer, since 1973. However, the scarce information available about it online doesn't credit as being the world's first, or with providing any inspiration for the British programme. What was then the first lottery to take place on television?

Comment: Can we have out of the box ones? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draft_lottery_(1969)

Answer (score 2):

I can get up to 1957.

It is the first for the first broadcast of the Spanish *Lotería de Navidad* (Christmas lottery), as stated [here](http://www.rtve.es/rtve/20161108/cinco-cosas-probablemente-no-sabias-loteria-navidad/1438624.shtml)(warning: link in Spanish) and other sources.

It is worth commenting:

- The Christmas lottery was the main lottery event of the year, so I would guess that regular (weekly) lottery events would not be broadcast until later.
- Originally it was just broadcast, without any anchorman (the first one would appear in 1966)